# How to expose a dependency when writing a grunt module

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm building a module `grunt-foo` which is utilizing `grunt-galvanize` (e.g. its in my `package.json` as a dependency). Something like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt)

  grunt.registerMultiTask('foo', 'do your foo', function() {
    grunt.task.run('bar');
  });

  grunt.registerTask('bar', function() {
     // Add some galvanize configs
     grunt.option('galvanizeConfig', { configs: { ... } });
     grunt.task.run(['galvanize:baz'])
  });

  grunt.registerTask('baz', function() { grunt.log.ok('baz'); });
};
```

However, when I utilize this grunt module in an app and run `grunt foo` I get something like `Warning: Task "galvanize:baz" not found. Use --force to continue.`

I'm looking for a solution that does not involve my having to install `grunt-galvanize` as a dependency (dev or otherwise) within the apps that will utilize my grunt module.

Comment: You okay with adding that as your grunt tasks dependency? If yes then you have missed the `grunt.loadNpmTasks('galvanize')` in your code.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear - `grunt-galvanize` is already added as a dependency and it's included via `require(load-grunt-tasks)(grunt);` bit.